# Looping through a shell array given as parameter

Tags: bash, shell-script, array

I'm trying to write up a little helper script that will change permissions and ownership to some sites on a server.

Right now, I can either pass in 1 site, or do all via simply skipping that argument.

What I am finding is that I need to be able to apply to multiple sites on the server, but not all, so I tried making an attempt at passing an array via:

```
SLIST=("my.site.com" "your.site.com")
./website-perms 644 755 kevin "${SLIST[@]}"
```

However, it only does the first item in the array `my.site.com`

How do I fix this so I can pass in an array of sites?

**FULL CODE**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Done nightly, and copied to /usr/bin/
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
   exit 1
fi
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "usage: ./website-perms.sh fileperm folderperm owner (1|2) (1=kevin,2=www-data) (optional) Site Array"
    exit 1
fi

function chg_perms() {
    echo "find $1 -type f -exec chmod $2 {} \\";
    echo "find $1 -type d -exec chmod $3 {} \\";
    find $1 -type f -exec chmod $2 {} \;
    find $1 -type d -exec chmod $3 {} \;
    echo "-- chg_perms done";
}

function chg_owner() {
    echo "chown -R $2:www-data $1";
    chown -R $2:www-data $1;
    echo "-- chg_owner done";
}

SITES=$4;
if [ -z $SITES ]; then
    for dir in /var/www/httpdocs/*/
    do
        dir=${dir%*/}
        chg_perms "/var/www/httpdocs/${dir##*/}" $1 $2
        chg_owner "/var/www/httpdocs/${dir##*/}" $3
    done;
else
    for dir in "${SITES[@]}" #ONLY DOES THE FIRST ITEM
    do
        chg_perms "/var/www/httpdocs/$dir" $1 $2
        chg_owner "/var/www/httpdocs/$dir" $3
    done
fi;
```

Comment: Instead of `$EUID -ne 0`, I would use `$(id -n) -ne 0`.  Environment variables are not reliable for that test, and EUID is a non-POSIX extension. Try this: `EUID=0 bash -c 'echo $EUID'`. And this: `sh -c 'echo $EUID'`

Comment: The simple answer: when you run the script with the command you gave above, your array is expanded *before your script ever sees it*.  So from the perspective of the script, you didn't pass it 4 arguments, the 4th of which is an array—you passed it 5 arguments (since your array has 2 elements), the 4th of which is the first item of the array.

Comment: BTW, the perms for both files and dirs can be set in one command: `chmod ug=rwX,o=rX`.  Note that's a capital-X, not lowercase.  It sets only directories to executable.  And if you want all new files created in the dir to be group-owned by the dir's group, that's when you need to run a 2nd `chmod` to add setgid to the directories with `find $1 -type d -exec chmod g+s {} +`

Comment: The usual technique of passing an array as all-the-remaining-args (which the existing answers describe).  AFAIK, this is the *only* way possible with bash.  It's not possible to `export` array variables into the environment, so you can't do something like `avar=('foo bar' 'a*b*') ./bash-array-arg.sh avar` to put an array in the environment, and give its name to the called program.  The bash manual says "not yet", so a future bash may support it.  BTW, when you use that syntax, the resulting env var is a scalar that includes the parens, like if you used `avar='(...)'`.  I didn't check zsh.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nice script.  Usually I would use all remaining arguments as the list of sites.  Something like this (I have not tested these mods):

```
if [ $# -lt 3 ]; then
    echo >&2 "usage: $0 fileperm folderperm owner [site ...]"
    exit 1
fi
```

[ . . . ]

```
fileperm="$1"
folderperm="$2"
owner="$3"
shift 3             # shift first 3 args off of list

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    for dir in /var/www/httpdocs/*/    #stackexchange syntax coloring fix*/
    do
        dir="${dir%/*}"
        chg_perms "/var/www/httpdocs/${dir##*/}" "$fileperm" "$folderperm"
        chg_owner "/var/www/httpdocs/${dir##*/}" "$owner"
    done;
else
    for dir           # step through positional args ($1,$2,...,$N)
    do
        chg_perms "/var/www/httpdocs/$dir" "$fileperm" "$folderperm"
        chg_owner "/var/www/httpdocs/$dir" "$owner"
    done
fi
```

Comment: Thanks Robert.  `for dir`??? how would this iterate a potential in-determintate amount of items?

Comment: By definition, that's how the `for` loop works in the shell.  Look at the shell manpage: `man sh`.  It clearly describes this.  You are guaranteed that the loop will iterate once for each positional parameter (`$1`, `$2`,...) with `$dir` set to the value of each one in succession.

Comment: Just to emphasize: using `shift 3` to remove the first 3 arguments from the positional parameters, then `for dir do ...` will iterate over the remaining positional parameters.

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, thanks.  Here's an easy example, paste this at the prompt: `set -- 1 2 3 4 5; shift 3; for i; do echo $i; done`

Comment: @Kevin This is the common idiom to iterate over indeterminate number of command line arguments in a shell script.

Comment: `for dir` is the same as `for dir in "$@"`, `in "$@"` is the default.  IMO it's better to be explicit than implicit when writing scripts, even for something as common as this.

Answer (score 5):

A slightly different take, although I prefer RobertL's approach

```
sites=( "${@:4}" )
# ...
for dir in "${sites[@]}"; do ...
```

- To declare an array, you must use parentheses.
- `"${@:4}"` takes the positional parameters, starting from $4 until the end.
- get out of the habit of using ALLCAPSVARNAMES: leave them to be restricted for the shell's use only.

Comment: Thanks for this glenn, q4u, why point 3?

Comment: It's easy to [make mistakes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28310594/7552).

Comment: @Kevin, not only is Glenn's point good practice, it's actually endorsed by POSIX; see fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell and environment variables share a namespace.